# Unique index on text column - what is the index type?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

In my table I have column `slug` of type `TEXT`. It will store slug that will be used for queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE slug = 'my-post-slug'
```

For now I set up `unique` index on slug.

1. What is the type of unique index (btree, hash, ...)?
2. Is it enough or I should add second index on `slug` column of type `hash`?

Comment: So all you do is testing for equality with `=`? No pattern-matching? Also: always provide your version of Postgres.

Comment: yes only equality, postgres v = 9.3

Comment: Then you are covered by a_horse's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

re 1)

If you don't specify an index type, it defaults to btree.

re 2)

Yes, a btree index is enough. hash indexes are generally considered as not very efficient in Postgres. Plus they have some drawbacks.

[Quote from the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html)

> *Hash index operations are not presently WAL-logged, so hash indexes might need to be rebuilt with REINDEX after a database crash if there were unwritten changes. Also, changes to hash indexes are not replicated over streaming or file-based replication after the initial base backup, so they give wrong answers to queries that subsequently use them. **For these reasons, hash index use is presently discouraged**.*

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: B-tree is not just default. *Currently, only B-tree indexes can be declared unique.* http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-unique.html